# I get all the lines inside the printf line in the end of the output

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-2020-06

the code:
[image: the code]

the output:
[image: the output]

I just started learning c. So, I did a simple sum program.

The code looks like this...

```
Int main(void){
    Printf("enter numbers");
    Int n1,n2;
    Scanf("%d%d",&n1,&n2);
    Sum=n1+n2;
    Printf("sum= %d",sum);
}
```

when I build the program, there are no errors or warnings, but the console is empty. I can still type in two numbers and it gives the sum too.

```
33
66
enter numberssum=99
```

I want the entered number displayed when I hit run, not after finding the sum.

I use the eclipse ide for c&c++ 2020-06

Comment: Post the exact code you have along with the output and description of the problem. As of now, it's not clear.

Comment: Are you certain that you have uploaded the right code? The program you have uploaded has syntactical errors and there is no way it should compile without errors and warnings in the present state.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. The shown code is not C (or you have omitted some very important declaratins and definitions. That and very likely also your immediate problem, can be solved by finding a HelloWorld program and studying it.

Comment: The output in the terminal is "line buffered". It will only show if there is a '\n' in the output.

Comment: The 'terminal' environment that Eclipse gives you isn't the same as the ordinary terminal environment.  I'm not sure that there's a fix for it — if there was, it would be done automatically.